# Extracting a TLD from the content and assign to custom field

Tags: posts, custom-field, filters

I am trying to get the first instance of a TLD in a post and insert it into a custom field. For example with a post:

> Hi I am Bob. My website is http://bob.com and you can reach me at
>   bob@bob.com

I want to insert "bob.com" into the custom field "user_domain"
I am using the action 'publish_post' so that when a user publishes a post it automatically assigns the found domain to the custom field.

I have been trying for a couple hours and have come up with:

```
    $content = strtolower($content);
function filterdomain($content) {
$founddomain = preg_match('/^[-a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/', $content);
return $content;
      add_post_meta($post['ID'], 'user_domain', $founddomain);
}
add_filter('content_save_pre','filterdomain');
add_action('publish_post', 'filterdomain');
```

This (as you can probably see) is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Tai

Comment: you return **before** setting the post meta

Answer (score 0):

First, your `return` statement is before you actually add the meta data, so your hook is terminating before it can do that. Remember that `return` ends the function it's within, so only put it at the very end or in places you want it to short-circuit.

Second, your RegEx is a little off; you shouldn't be using the ^ and $ markers since you're trying to match a domain name *anywhere* within the text.

Here's a patter that may do the job:

`/(?<=^|\/|\s)([\w\-\.]+\.\w+)(?=^|\/|\s)/`

This will match `bob.com`, but not `bob@bob.com` because the `(?<=)` and `(?=)` bits tells it to only consider matches that are preceded/followed by the beginning/end of the string, a forward slash, or a whitespace character. You'll probably need to play around with those lists to make sure it doesn't accidentally grab something else, or miss a valid entry surrounded by other stuff like HTML.